# How to protect routes in polka js

Tags: node.js, routes, authorization

I am trying to implement protected routes using polka js. I tried to implement it using a middleware but i keep getting unauthorized even for the unprotected route.

```
const polka = require('polka');
const send = require('@polka/send-type');

const app = polka();

app.get('/un-protected', (req, res) => {
  return send(res, 200, {
    msg: 'Unprotected route',
  });
});

const auth = false;

app
  .use((req, res, next) => {
    if (auth) {
      next();
    } else {
      return send(res, 401, {
        errors: {
          msg: 'unauthorized',
        },
      });
    }
  })
  .get('/protected', (req, res) => {
    return send(res, 200, {
      msg: 'Protected route',
    });
  });

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));
```

The expected behaviour is that only the  '/protected' route should show unauthorized message but currently even for the '/un-protected' route the unauthorized message keeps popping up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The authentication check should be placed between the specified route and the action when going to the protected route.

```
app.get('/un-protected', (req, res) => {
  return send(res, 200, {
    msg: 'Unprotected route',
  });
});

const auth = false;

const checkAuth = (req, res, next) => {
  if (auth) {
    next();
  } else {
    return send(res, 401, {
      errors: {
        msg: 'unauthorized',
      },
    });
  }
}

app
  .get('/protected', checkAuth, (req, res) => {
    return send(res, 200, {
      msg: 'Protected route',
    });
  });
```